# How to mark a Salesforce Contract record as canceled or terminated?

Tags: bestpractice, design-patterns, contracts

I understand once a contract has been Activated, the status cannot be changed. However, there are times when a contract is terminated (ends early) and there needs to be a way to indicate this.

Are there any best practices for indicating a Salesforce Contract record has been terminated (canceled)?

Comment: just adding this here for reference purposes [Contract Management Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213363&type=1)

Comment: and Im pretty sure this can come in handy as well [Trailhead - Manage Contracts and Renewals](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/sf_cpq/units/sf_cpq_manage_contracts_renewals)

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, an activated contract *can* still be edited, as long as the user has permission to do so. The best practice is one of business process, less of system configuration. For example, after adding a new contract status labeled "Terminated" that is in the "Activated" category, you could adopt the following business process.

1. AE sends an email to the Salesforce admin team requesting contract termination, with the regional sales manager on cc
2. Salesforce admin changes the contract status to "Terminated"

Configuring the "Terminated" status to also be in the "Activated" category ensures that the contract remains [read-only by default](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contract_activate.htm&type=5) to most users even after the status change. You can also expand this process to include a **Terminated Date** and **Terminated Reason**, which the AE can supply in the email request.

If you want other non-admin, super users to be able to handle contract terminations, you could create and assign a permission set with the following permissions.

- **Edit** permission on the **Contract** object
- **Activate Contracts** permission

tl;dr Salesforce permissions will allow you to empower some subset of users to terminate contracts using the standard **Status** field, once you figure out the right business process with checks and balances for your organization.